# Convert commits from git into json array/json object not working (Nodejs)

Tags: json, node.js, git

Hello I'm trying to format my json in this when I have a long array [] and then json objects in {}. Right now I am getting a wierd format where the name of my objects are saving in wrong format. e.g rather than "commit":"commitname", its saying as "commit commit name" below is my code that I am using to do this:

```
 function put(error, stdout, stderr) {
    var commitsbybranch = JSON.stringify(stdout.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(e) { return e.substring(0);}).filter(function(e) { return e; }));
    var commitsObj2 = JSON.parse(commitsbybranch);
    console.log(commitsObj2.length);
 function toObject(commitsbybranch) {
    var ss = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < commitsbybranch.length; ++i)
    ss[i] = commitsbybranch[i];
    return ss;

     }


    fs.writeFile('reacted/public/testcommitsbybranch.json', commitsbybranch);
}
```

My json looks like this now:

```
["commit commitname",","Merge: 27755ba 5c51","Author: Harsharan <harsharan@coolio.com>","Date:   Mon Feb 29 18:01:11 2016 +0000","commit commitname2",","Merge: 27755ba 5c51","Author: Harsharan <harsharan@coolio.com>","Date:   Mon Feb 29 18:01:11 2016 +0000"]
```

Please help me resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the result of `git log 'branchName'`. Try this:

```
function put(error, stdout, stderr) {
        var log = stdout.split(/\r?\n/);
        var json = [];
        var commitInfo = {};
        for(var i in log){
            var str = log[i];
            if(str.match(/^commit\s+/)){
                var split = str.split(/^commit\s+/);
                commitInfo['commit'] = split[1];
            }
            if(str.match(/^Author:\s+/)){
                var split = str.split(/^Author:\s+/);
                commitInfo['Author'] = split[1];
            }
            if(str.match(/^Date:\s+/)){
                var split = str.split(/^Date:\s+/);
                commitInfo['Date'] = split[1];
            }
            if(str.match(/^\s+/)){
                var split = str.split(/^\s+/);
                commitInfo['message'] = split[1];
            }
            else if(commitInfo['commit'] != undefined && commitInfo['Author'] != undefined && commitInfo['Date'] != undefined && commitInfo['message'] != undefined){
                json.push(commitInfo);
                commitInfo = {};
            }
        }
        var commitsbybranch = JSON.stringify(json);
        fs.writeFile('reacted/testcommitsbybranch.json', commitsbybranch);
    }
```